# Dynamo db table design- Create a new table or add a column in existing table

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I need some advice on dynamo db design

There are some few params that needs to be added into our DB

Should these new params:

1.Added in the old existing table

2.New table for them

Important thing to note is if we add new params in already existing tables then it would be populated for around ~10% of data coming in.

I don't think costing will be impacted in both the scenarios(LMK if i am thinking wrong)
But mostly what would be the advisable practice

LMK if any input is required from my side

Answer (score 2):

A DynamoDB table allows you to [add arbitrary attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.UpdateItem.html) to the existing items in the table.

Copying over to a new table is perhaps unnecessary, as this will cost you some read and write capacity/request units with no apparent benefit.